# Как включить панель для рисования в Visual Studio WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: С№]

Не могу найти вообще информации как добавить эту панельку слева для рисования и добавления примитивных ассетов.

Comment: А откуда у вас такой скрин?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3979ahvQAQ

Comment: Это не студия, а `Blend`

Comment: спасибо, большое

Answer (score 2):

Использовать Blend Visual Studio